# Why script is not working in Centos 6.3 minimal

Tags: bash, console, centos

trying with script automaticly create directions and permissions for users .

at first I am adding users

```
# adduser mysite.com
# adduser mysite1.com
# adduser mysite2.com
# adduser mysite3.com
```

after that, to not create direction manualy, I write the following script

```
cd /home
for dir in `ls -1 `; do
mkdir /home/$dir/log
mkdir /home/$dir/html
chown -R $dir:apache $dir
chmod ug+rX $dir
done;
```

but get the following error

"mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/\033[0m\033[01;34mlog\033[0m/log': No such file or directory..." and etc

what do I do wrong ? In old VPS all were ok, but in new VPS I got that error

Comment: Your clue's here: `/home/\033[0m\033[01;34mlog\033[0m/log`. I believe that comes out of `ls -1`. If you really want to look for directory contents for later processing, do not use `ls`, use something else like `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to use `ls` there, change it to this:

```
for dir in `ls --color=never -1 `; do
```

Using `*` would simplify this:

```
for dir in *; do
```

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure that you use only directories in this way:

```
 for dir in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`; do
```

As Sean wrote: `ls` adds colors to directories' names and you have to ensure that there are no additional information by using his solution or `find`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work because `ls` is generating escape sequences for the terminal to display colors.